# Linked List in C without malloc

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, free

Is it possible to insert an `unsigned long` into a linked list ordered from smallest to largest without dynamic memory, using `malloc` or `free`?

Comment: You can use an array to store integers in the list.

Comment: Can you explain it with an example? Sorry I am new to C

Comment: All you need is to write a function that inserts integers in an array in the given order.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But that wouldn't make it "a linked list", would it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked Lists in C without malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856317/linked-lists-in-c-without-malloc)

Comment: @unwind It will be a linked list. The array is simply is an allocator.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: No it won't be.

Comment: @WedaPashi You can use different allocators with the same data structure. And an array is one of allocators. See also the answer to the question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sure, you can use an array to get the storage, but that's not what your original comment sounded like, which is why I questioned it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Blam! With all due respect to you, (but) Don't be surprised if I take that too personal and offensive. (BTW, its *qualification*, I assume a good programmer is good with keyboards as well)

Answer (score 4):

You can pre-allocate a bunch of list entries in the form of an array, then pick entries from that array when you do an insert. This is of course only possible if the array is either global, or at otherwise kept in scope for the duration of the insertion operation.

Something like:

```
struct integerNode {
  int                value;
  struct integerNode *next;
};

struct integerNode nodes[100]; /* adjust for your number of integers */
```

The next step would be to use a trivial `for` loop to link the items in `nodes` together, forming a linked list of free items. Then write a function that de-links a node from the free list and links it into another list, while inserting the number.