# 2D Linked List R Programming Language

Tags: r, linked-list

How I could build a 2 dimensional linked list in R?

Comment: I think you may need to be more expasnsive about what operations you expect to be applied to such an object. R uspports lists of lists, but that may not be what yoo mean by a "2d linked list".

Answer (score 1):

For a linked list you need pointers, which R does not have (although in C++ a linked list can be [implemented using no pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002764/using-c-is-a-linked-list-implementation-without-using-pointers-possible-or-not)). The basic R data structures are lists, data.frames, arrays etc, linked lists seem a bit to low level for R. If you provide more background as to what you want, we might be able to advise a suitable data structure in R.