# List using with references, changes behavior when used as a member

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, reference, const-reference

Experimenting with this question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50649120/225186 I produced what seems to be a legal recursive self referential class that implements a circular list:

```
struct node{
    int val;
    node const& next;
};

int main(){
    node s{3, {4, s}};

    assert(s.val == 3);
    assert(s.next.val == 4);
    assert(&s.next.next == &s);
    assert(s.next.next.val == 3);
}
```

However, when I try put this as a member of a larger class I get a warning from the compiler and the behavior changes.

```
struct A{
    node n;
    int i;
    A(int a, int b) : n{a, {b, n}}{} // warning here, also tried n{a, node{b, n}}
};

int main(){
    A a(3, 4);
    assert( a.n.val == 3 );
    assert(&(a.n.next.next) == &(a.n)); // this assert fail and 
    assert( a.n.next.val == 4 ); // segmentation fault here
}
```

The warning I get is `gcc:  warning: a temporary bound to ‘A::n’ only persists until the constructor exits [-Wextra]`.
I don't believe that the warning is correct, however it is consistent with the later runtime error.

I admit that the class is non-conventional, however, **how can it be that a class that it changes behavior inside a class?**

**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate initialization allows binding references to temporaries ([and this causes lifetime extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313292/aggregate-reference-member-and-temporary-lifetime)).  Your first example is [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) because `node` is an aggregate.

However, in a constructor member initializer list, it is ill-formed to bind a reference to a temporary (C++17 class.base.init/11). This is because there is no lifetime extension in that situation , and allowing it would inevitably produce a dangling reference.  In the second example `node` is not an aggregate because it has a user-provided constructor.

Comment: Thank you, very clear. You are right, if I remove the constructor and do aggregate initialization `A a{ {3, {4, a.n}}, 99 };` then it works. However, I can't remove the custom constructor for `A`, do you see any workaround?

Comment: @alfC not really; this idea is probably more of a curiosity than a thing of practical use

Comment: Actually, I have an use for it, I need a unmutable list that can be constructed in the stack (without managing heap memory).