# How to implement linked list in reference without using pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linked-list

In Java, a reference can be initialized to null. However, in C++, it will cause a problem. So not sure how to use reference-only to implement the linked list.

Comment: You can't. Use pointers.

Comment: @lightrek Have you considered using smart pointers. Like unique_ptr?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a Linked-List implementation without using pointers possible or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002764/is-a-linked-list-implementation-without-using-pointers-possible-or-not)

Comment: Linked List is a dynamic data structure and reference is compile time construct. So, you cannot use reference to implement linked list in very basic way.

Comment: A Java reference is much more similar to a C++ pointer than to a C++ reference. They're different languages, they use different terminology.

Comment: References in `Java` are like *pointers* in `C++` so use *pointers*.

Comment: The problem is not so much that a reference can't be null, than that a reference can't be reassigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how useful the concept is, but you CAN do it using `std::reference_wrapper,` as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 2, b = 6, c = 1;

    list<reference_wrapper<int>> mylist;
    mylist.push_back(a);
    mylist.push_back(b);
    mylist.push_back(c);

    for(auto x : mylist) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    a = 3; // <- this setting will modify mylist!

    for(auto x : mylist) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would recommend learning C++ ways of handling things, specially that you are coming from Java world. [Demo!](http://ideone.com/3G2MxL)

Comment: While your answer is correct. It may be beyond the understanding of OP, who isn't well aware of pointers/references in C++. No offense to anyone!

Comment: @Ajay I agree. But, I just wanted to show possibilities :)

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure why you would want to use references in c++ since a reference cannot be null in C++ like you said. What would you do if you get to the end of the linked list.

Your only solution (Since you are new to c++) is to use pointers like this.

```
struct Node{
   int value;
   Node* next;
}
```

This way you can leave the pointer called next as null and that would signify the end of the linked list.